# Standard Way to Update Path?

Tags: macos, installation, path

I recently installed Apache Maven on Mac OS X.

apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz

I gunzipped this file to /Users/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4.

Then, I updated my $PATH to include /Users/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4./bin.

Is this acceptable, or is there a standard place to put external binaries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `bin` directory to your $PATH is quite acceptable. External 3rd party binaries should be placed in `/opt` directory. [Filesystem hierarchy](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) should be followed & consistant.

```
/opt/<provider or package>/bin
```

Maven's [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Unix-based_Operating_Systems_Linux_Solaris_and_Mac_OS_X) encourages installation under `/usr/local/apache-maven/<package>`. This is also a common practice, but I found updating $PATH can be an unnecessary headache with package version updates & rollbacks. Instead, I'll place each package under `/opt`, and create a symbolic link to `/usr/local/maven`. At which point, I'd update $PATH to `/usr/loca/maven/bin` and update the link as needed.

#### How I'd install Maven

- Extract downloaded package to `/opt` directory

  - `cd /opt`
  - `tar zvxf ~/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz`
- Create symbolic link

  - `ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.0.4 /usr/local/maven`
- Update $PATH

  - `echo "export $PATH=/usr/local/maven/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile`
  - `source ~/.bash_profile`

#### If and when a new version comes along

Repeat the above steps; except, remove old link first.

- Remove old link

  - `rm /usr/local/maven`
- Recreate link to new version

  - `ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.0.5 /usr/local/maven`

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. So you just copy the bin directory of a folder to /opt, but then you'll also have a duplicate copy under /usr/local/maven/bin, and update your $PATH to /usr/local/maven/bin?

Comment: Copy maven _in it's entirety_ to `opt`. So you'll have `/opt/apache-maven-3.0.4`. I'll update the answer to include steps I'd follow.